# 3 Broken Package that will not be removed; so that I can update Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I have done `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

**After that it gives me the following error message**

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.  
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 acl : Depends: libacl1 (= 2.2.52-1) but 2.2.52-2 is installed  
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) but 2.19-18 is installed  
 udev : Breaks: plymouth (< 0.9.0-7) but 0.8.8-0ubuntu17.1 is installed  
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

**When I use Synaptic Package Manager it says that I've got "3 broken packages". Which I am unable to remove; they are as follows**

1. acl - 2.2.51-1
2. libc6-dbg - 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
3. udev - 215-17+deb8u1

**When I mark them "for removal". It then prompts me with the following message**

```
Essential packages will be removed.  
This may render your system unusable!
```

**I accept the warning which results in the following message being displayed.**

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to lock the download directory
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get -f install && sudo dpkg -a --configure`